# when is criteria better than HQL or nativeSQL Query?

Tags: java, hibernate

In my Case after getting a certain list I need to to iterate that list to set some other fields of the POJO class.

```
 if (transportHeaderList.get(i) instanceof TransportHeaderIiss){
     transHeadIiss=(TransportHeaderIiss)transportHeaderList.get(i);
     customerVendor= tOManagementDAO.getVendorCode(transHeadIiss.getCustVendUid());
 }
 if(customerVendor!=null){
     transHeadIiss.setVendorCode(customerVendor.getCustVendCode());
 }
```

The Above code calls `getVendorCode` method to get `custVendorCode` value from the database. The code for `getVendorCode` is as follows

```
public CustomerVendorIiss getVendorCode(Long custVendUid) {
    List list=new ArrayList();
    /* Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(CustomerVendorIiss.class);

     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("companyCode",user.getDefaultCompany().getCompanyCode()));
     if(custVendUid!=null && custVendUid.intValue()>0)
     {
         criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("custVendUid",custVendUid));

     }
     list=criteria.list();*/
     UsersIiss user= ApplicationContextProvider.getLoggedInUser();
     String sqlQuery="select custVendCode as custVendCode from CustomerVendorIiss where companyCode ='"+ user.getDefaultCompany().getCompanyCode() +"' and custVendUid= "+custVendUid;
     Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sqlQuery);
     query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CustomerVendorIiss.class));
     list=query.list();
        if(list.size()>0){
        return (CustomerVendorIiss)list.get(0);
        }else{
        return null;
        }
}
```

When I executed above code with criteria, it took a lot time to get the values from table and set it to POJO class and sometimes I would get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error . I guess that's because I am not de-allocating the criteria object.

when I executed the above code using `createQuery()` method I did not run into that issue and all that process of getting and setting was faster.

I want to understand what is that I am doing wrong here?
it would be great to know how and when criteria is better or HQL is better ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Actually these queries are different. The second one has an additional restriction

```
companyCode ='"+ user.getDefaultCompany().getCompanyCode() +"'
```

So try to add the same to the criteria

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("companyCode",user.getDefaultCompany().getCompanyCode()));
```

Also it's not god to concate strings this way to get the query. SQL injection is possible. Use parameters instead.

Criteria and HQL is better than SQL in one case - you need DB independent logic to swap DB when necessary without rewriting code.

Comment: L .. Thank you for responding :) How do I add the same restriction companyCode ='"+ user.getDefaultCompany().getCompanyCode() +"' to criteria.. I thought criteria.add(restriction()) is the only way to add restriction to criterias.  When I used criteria I got an error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error". why is this error thrown while using criteria if you could let me know.? Thanks again